# Something working on most systems but not everywhere c#

Tags: c#, windows, raspberry-pi

I have a console application in C# for Windows and RPi (Mono). I make a filelist and store it in an array. Then there are two files which I don't want in that list, so I want to remove those from the list. This works on most systems where the application runs (Windows and RPi's alike) but  there is one RPi - so far - where it refuses to delete one of those files from the list. As if it cannot find the file (because I don't get the message within the if-statement). I am looking for possible causes. Any suggestions?

```
  MonthfileList = Directory.GetFiles("data/", "*log.txt");

  for (int i=0; i<MonthfileList.Length; i++)
  {
    if (MonthfileList[i].Contains("alltimelog") )
    {
      Sup.LogDebugMessage(message: $"MonthfileList removing: {MonthfileList[i]}");
      var foos = new List<string>(MonthfileList);
      foos.RemoveAt(i);
      MonthfileList = foos.ToArray();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possibly you are not aware, that linux (RPi) filesystem is case sensitive, whereas Windows is not. So the file Example.txt and example.txt are different files on linux and the same file on windows.

Comment: That loop doesn't seems to be correct. You are skipping the test on the file following the one that you remove.

Comment: @ThomasVoß  Thanks for the comments. I am aware of the case sensitivity and that seems OK and not the cause.

Comment: @Steve that might be a good point. I'll check that and come back to  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stated problem could happen if you have two files with the required string stored in your array MonthFileList in two adiacent indexes. 
In this case, the logic inside the loop causes the second file to be evaluated.

Suppose you have an array of 5 elements (index 0-4) where at index 2 and 3 there is a file with the searched word.
When the first index is evaluated (2) the file is removed from the list, then you rebuild the array without the removed file, but this has a secondary effect. The file that was at index 3 is now at index 2 and your indexer that was at 2 is incremented to 3, thus the old element, now at index 2, is not evaluated and remains into the array.

Fix is simple. loop backwards

```
// Invert logic, so you don't need a conversion list/array each time you find a match
var foos = new List<string>(MonthfileList);
for (int i=foos.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (foos[i].Contains("alltimelog") )
   {
       Sup.LogDebugMessage(message: $"MonthfileList removing: {foos[i]}");
       foos.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
MonthfileList = foos.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Steve made the correct hint. I changed the code with i-- to account for the missing entry:

```
  MonthfileList = Directory.GetFiles("data/", "*log.txt");

  for (int i=0; i<MonthfileList.Length; i++)
  {
    if (MonthfileList[i].Contains("alltimelog") )
    {
      Sup.LogDebugMessage(message: $"MonthfileList removing: {MonthfileList[i]}");
      var foos = new List<string>(MonthfileList);
      foos.RemoveAt(i--);
      MonthfileList = foos.ToArray();
    }
  }
```